# Distinguish direct and indirect dependencies of a binary on Linux?

Tags: dependencies, shared-library

`ldd` on Linux will give the list of all shared libraries on which a given binary depends. This is usually much more extensive than the libraries that were listed on the linker command line used to create the binary: it will include most if not all dependencies of those libraries.

Is it possible to determine just the list of libraries that were linked explicitly (i.e. the direct dependencies) and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `readelf -d` to dump the "dynamic" section of the binary.  This will include NEEDED libraries.

For example, comparing `ldd` with `readelf` on `/bin/ls`:

```
$ ldd /bin/ls
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff190da000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f082f94e000)
        libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f082f749000)
        libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f082f540000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f082f172000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f082ef10000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f082ed0c000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f082fb75000)
        libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f082eb07000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f082e8eb000)

$ readelf -d /bin/ls | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libselinux.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcap.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libacl.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

You can also do this on `.so` files

```
$ readelf -d /lib64/libpcre.so.1 | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Comment: Turns out that these NEEDED dependencies are even listed in the order that they were specified on the linker commandline (for the few binaries where I checked this at least).

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to list direct dependencies *recursively,* use `lddtree` from pax-utils:

```
$ lddtree /bin/file
/bin/file (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
    libmagic.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1
        libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib/libzstd.so.1
        liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5
        libbz2.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1
    libseccomp.so.2 => /usr/lib/libseccomp.so.2
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

(This internally uses python-pyelftools.)